# How to calculuate $E(XY)$?

Tags: probability, covariance, means

Here's a question:

> Tossing a fair cube 6 times.
>
> Let $X$ = *number of tosses gave 1*, and let $Y$ = *number of tosses gave 2*.
>
> Calculate $Cov(X, Y)$.

I know that $Cov(X, Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$.

I need help to find $E(XY)$. What is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could find the distribution of $XY$. Then the expectation of $XY$ can be calculated in the usual way.  A fair bit of work!

Alternately, let $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th toss is a $1$, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Let $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th toss is a $2$, and $0$ otherwise. Then $X=X_1+\cdots +X_6$ and $Y=Y_1+\cdots+Y_6$. So we want
$$E((X_1+\cdots+X_6)(Y_1+\cdots+Y_6)).$$
Imagine expanding the product.  We get a sum of terms $X_iY_i$, and of terms $X_iY_j$ where $i\ne j$.

Now use the linearity of expectation. We have $X_iY_i=0$, so the expectation of these terms is $0$.

For the $30$ terms of the shape $X_iY_j$ where $i\ne j$, note that $X_iY_j=1$ with probability $\frac{1}{36}$, so $E(X_iY_j)=\frac{1}{36}$. It follows that $E(XY)=\frac{30}{36}$.